# How can I combine the python logging cookbook example of logging network events with a logging.config.listen thread?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Theoretically this should be simple. Taking the example from the logging cookbook here:

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network

I want to add the ability to change the logging configuration on the fly. I simply added:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(...) # setup the root logger
config_thread = logging.config.listen()
config_thread.start()
tcpserver = LogRecordSocketReceiver()
```

and on startup, this works fine with the provided example of sending log events across the network to the socket receiver.

However, the problem occurs once I send in a new configuration. After that the log server won't produce any more logging messages. That happens even though each `handleLogRecord()` call gets a new instance of the logger through `logging.getLogger()`.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that in the configuration dictionary, you have `disable_existing_loggers` set to `False`. Otherwise, when a new configuration is applied, the existing loggers will be disabled and not produce any more output.